# Pisa arabic rendering issue using xhtml2pdf and reportlab

Tags: django, reportlab, pisa, xhtml2pdf

Arabic goes wrong displayed on output pdf with the following code:

```
template = get_template(template_src)
context = Context(context_dict)
html = template.render(context)
result = StringIO.StringIO()    
pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(StringIO.StringIO(
        html.encode(pdf_encoding)), result, encoding=pdf_encoding) # pdf_encoding = 'utf-8'
```

and in the template I set charset and fonts:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
@font-face {
              font-family: AmiriRegular;
              src: url(/usr/share/fonts/opentype/fonts-hosny-amiri/amiri-regular.ttf);
            }
            body { font-family: AmiriRegular; }
```

the output:
[image]

The Arabic text in snapshot is supposed to be:

```
ياسر حسن
```

Comment: What is the template supposed to be? It is neither valid HTML nor valid CSS.

Comment: HTML and CSS are okay, but the  word is separated characters which is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think one solution is to pass those arabic text manually and reshape them using these two libraries:

```
import arabic_reshaper
from bidi.algorithm import get_display

reshaped_text = arabic_reshaper.reshape('your desired text in arabic')
bidi_text = get_display(reshaped_text)
```